# Python and ETL: Job and workflow/task mamangent trigger and other concepts

Tags: python, etl, workflow, pipeline

i am writing a very simple ETL(T) pipline currently:

- look at ftp if new csv files exist
- if yes than donwload them
- Some initial Transformations
- bulk insert the individual CSVs into a MS sql DB
- Some additional Transformations

There can be alot of csv files. The srcript runs ok for the moment, but i have no concept of how to actually create a "managent" layer around this. Currently my pipeline runs linear. I have a list of the filenames that need to be loaded, and ( in a loop) i load them into the DB.

If something fails the whole pipeline has to rerun. I do not manage the state of the pipleine ( i.e. has an specific file already been downloaded and transformed/changed?).
There is no way to start from an intermediate point. How cold i break this down into individual taks that need to be performedß

I rougly now of tools like Airflow, but i feel that this is only a part of the necessary tools, and frankly i am to uneducated in this area to even ask the right questions.

It would be really nice if somebody could point me in the right direction of what i am missing and what tools are available.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I´m actually using Airflow to run etl-pipelines with similar steps described by you.
The whole workflow can be partitioned into single tasks. For almost every task Airflow provides an operator.

For

> look at ftp if new csv files exist

u could use a file sensor with underlying ftp-connection
[FileSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.4/_api/airflow/sensors/filesystem/index.html?highlight=filesensor#airflow.sensors.filesystem.FileSensor)

For

> if yes than donwload them

you could use the BranchPythonOperator.
[BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.4/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html?highlight=branchpython#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator)

All succeding tasks could be wrapped into a .py function and then be executed via the PythonOperator.

Would definitely recommend using Airflow, but if you are looking for alternatives, there are plenty:
[airflow-alternatives](https://hevodata.com/learn/airflow-alternatives/)